# Configure shell script execution every hour in ec2 instance using terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, shell, terraform

I have a shell script which i wanted to configure in AWS ec2 instance to run every hour. Iam using terraform to launch the ec2 instance. Is it possible to configure the shell script hourly execution through terraform itself while launching the ec2?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, in the aws_instance resource you can use the user_data argument to execute a script at launch that registers a cron job that executes hourly:

```
resource "aws_instance" "foo" {
  ami           = "ami-005e54dee72cc1d00" # us-west-2
  instance_type = "t2.micro"
  ...
  user_data = <<-EOF
    sudo service cron start
    echo '0 * * * * date >> ~/somefile' | crontab
  EOF
}
```

Ensure that NTP is configured on the instance and that you are using UTC for the system time.

Helpful links

- [AWS EC2 Documentation, User Data](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html)
- [POSIX crontab](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/crontab.html)
- [Terraform AWS provider, EC2 instance user_data](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/instance#user_data)